# Disabling acess to drives and desktop unless fill the compulsory html form

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to make a web page in jsp so that whenever my system is started, this page will automatically get opened and it will be mandatory for user to fill this form before going further.
If he try to avoid fulfilling this form ,he should not be able to access desktop or any drive in pc. please help if anyone knows.
Code my be in java/javascript/or css.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that what you are trying to do is not possible using a regular java web based application.

What you might look into is how to accomplish this using a regular java desktop application. Surely it is very hard to accomplish that limitations but i am sure there must be a way using java....